# Blender won't import my custom module, ImportError: No module named mymodule

Tags: add-on

My addon is in `/home/usr/.config/blender/2.68/scripts/addons/foldername`, has an `__init__.py` and cannot somehow import parts, that exist in the same folder. It says, 
`no module named mymodule` but from text editor it runs and work properly

What could be wrong here?

Comment: it solved: import sys sys.path.append('/home/$USER/.config/blender/2.68/scripts/addons/$FOLDER') or installetion with zip from BUP

Comment: Place an `__init__.py` file inside a folder to make it recognized as a Python module.

Comment: @Adhi, it is in. The last thing i found, it says, that it whants not id-parameter in registration, but rna... I don't know what he needs exactly

Comment: I forgot to say, we write custon nodes addon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can place your module into the folder `blender_directory/2.68/scripts/modules/` (so Blender can found it automatically), while your addon can stay in the `scripts/addons/foldername` folder with its `__init__.py` (and **not** `__index__.py`, by the way).

Or, you can go to `User Preferences`, tab `File`, and specify a custom extra folder for scripts, in the `scripts` input.
Note that this custom folder must contain 3 sub-directories : `addons`, `modules`, and `startup`.

[image]

In this example, your addon will of course be placed in :
`/home/user/scripts/blender/addons/yourAddon/`,
and the module(s) you want to import will be into :
`/home/user/scripts/blender/modules/`.

This way, **no need** to use `sys.path.append()`!

Comment: thanks you much but index is html tradition. here all scripts init

Answer (score 8):

Mostly this is a Python question, but it can be helpful to see working examples. Just like topology isn't strictly a Blender specific topic yet we still cover it sometimes. This reimport / and local imports topic is not necessarily obvious in a Blender add-on context.

If you have a folder called 'SomeAddon' and it contains the following files.

```
SomeAddon
Ͱ __init__.py
Ͱ resources.py
```

And you want to import a few functions from `resources.py` into `__init__.py`, then you do

```
from .resources import (function1, function2, function3)
```

This will work once, but when you go to reload python <kbd>F8</kbd> - as you will most likely do a lot during development - the changes you make to the functions `(function1, function2, function3)` will not be pulled in - `globals()` will still contain the cached versions of the old functions.

You can control what your add-on does during the *reload event* (triggered by <kbd>F8</kbd>). Most add-ons have some form of explicit reload of their modules. What tends to work is this (or something similar):

```
if 'resources' in globals():
    importlib.reload(resources)

from .resources import (function1, function2, function3)
```

The first time you enable the add-on, `resources` is hoisted into the globals for this module (your add-on). When you hit <kbd>F8</kbd> `resources` is already present and to update it you need to use [`importlib`'s reload function.](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload)

Answer (score 1):

You dont need all this. Just import from `__init__.py` like this:

```
from . mymodule import *
```

Or from a subfolder

```
from . subdir.mymodule import *
```

Comment: Please elaborate on _"You dont need all this."_  Recommend reading https://medium.com/@s16h/importing-star-in-python-88fe9e8bd4d2