# Need easy method to make SciPy available in my scripts

Tags: scripting, add-on

Thanks for taking notice, but in my original question I stated (I have put the operative part in bold font): 
"I would like to use SciPy special functions in Blender scripts, e.g:

```
from scipy import special as spe
```

I am running Blender 2.70a in OSX 10.8 on a MacBook Air, and making meshes from mathematical expressions. I have looked [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules-scipy) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3321/blender-wont-import-my-custom-module-importerror-no-module-named-mymodule) **but I am not experienced enough to do this yet.** Is it possible to have an answer of the format "download X file from Y site and put it in Z folder (for example /Applications/BlenderApplication/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/2.70/python/lib...), and possibly use the Blender User Preference/file tab to link to what I have downloaded?"

But my question was removed. I see the file scipy-0.14.0-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.6.dmg on sorcefogrge.net and I have downloaded it, but I need to understand exactly how so use this file to "install" it into the blender.app/Contents/MacOS/2.70/python/lib/python3.3 folder safely. If I do something wrong I am not in a position to know how to repair the damage. Is it really OK to install scipy for python 2.7 inside the 3.3 folder?

Besides the scipy.special submodule, another submodule would be helpful, so I need to use much of the python 2.7 scipy:
"Being able to use:

```
from scipy import fsolve
```

would also help me [here.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18513/script-method-to-trim-mesh-objects)"

Comment: This must have gone unnoticed in the review queue but as you said in another comment this isn't actually a dupe is it?

Comment: I'll ask a new, refined question soon. Thanks!