# How to access to Scipy.special functions within the script window

Tags: python

I would like to access the [special functions](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/special) in Scipy in the scripting window. I have looked at [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3321/blender-wont-import-my-custom-module-importerror-no-module-named-mymodule) and @polosson's answer in the first one suggests three possible ways to install a module in order to use it.

EDIT: My question is - **HOW** to install `scipy.special` into either the Blender Python path (which I should be able to find) or how to instal into a separate folder (which I would point to with the menu indicated in the third option of that answer).

Could someone take a moment to help me find a step-by-step way for me to start using scipy.special in the script window?  Thank You!

fyi I'm using Blender 2.70a on OSX 10.8.  Currently I run Python 2.7.6 using IDLE elsewhere in the computer, using [this](http://penandpants.com/2012/03/01/install-python-2/) method (indicative of my current installation experience  == clicking and dragging).

Comment: what operating system are you on @uhoh

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the question with OS and Blender versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to install scipy into Blender's python installation I would imagine for this to work.

Here are some clear instructions on how to do so: [Using 3rd party Python modules](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules)

Remember: Blender uses Python 3 so you will need to use the Python 3 version of scipy. The 2.7 version will not work.

Comment: Thanks DevTim - I've looked at that link a number of times (and I flagged it in my original question as well) but I need a little more. While I have no doubt that it serves as "clear instructions" to more experienced users, I need something a bit more step-by-step than "install it to use it."

Comment: The easiest way to install the library would be to download python 3 - the anaconda version already has scipy installed: http://continuum.io/downloads#py34 You can then either delete the blender python so it defaults to anaconda or you can drag the site packages folder from anaconda to the blender python. I would recommend you match the 32 bit anaconda with 32 bit blender, 64bit with 64 bit.

Comment: OK!  @DevTim that's a VERY helpful answer that even I understand! Thanks for your help. I'll give it a try in the morning (here).

Comment: Wow! Incredibly easy solution. This is exactly what I needed. One-step installation of anoconda, then just copy the scipy folder from site-packages in anoconda to site-packages in blender's python and bingo - dancing Bessel functions. Thanks again @DevTim

Comment: @ uhoh: No problem.