# Flexible Beam Simulation in Blender

Tags: modeling, python, soft-body

I am interested in simulating a flexible beam in blender, but I dont know how to do that. I did an FEM simulation using Python, however, I am interested in having a graphical beam in blender where I can input the modelling and have a visual output in blender. I have used other physics engine simulator, but the result wasnot good as the tool it self is based on linear euler bernoulli beam theory and to adjust that it was hard for me as it is written C ( I am not so much good in C programming). I dont know if there any suggestions concerning combining python code to the visualized beam in blender.

Comment: Do you need to visualize in Blender, or do you need to visualize your results?

Comment: "I did an FEM simulation using Python" What dependencies did it have? The Python in Blender supports NumPy, but last time I checked SciPy has to be put there manually like this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30427/5334 If you would like to run your simulation on the python in blender, that might be a fun way to start learning Blender by doing something in Python that you already know how to do, [like I did here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33993/5334)